# Redirect LTP1 to default printer over RDP

Tags: rdp, terminal-server, network-printer

Some older apps force the use of LPT1 for printing. In a terminal server environment, I am familiar with printer redirection over RDP using this syntax:

```
net use lpt1 \\tsclient\prn1
```

This would be much more useful if there were a way to redirect to their default printer as each client likely has a default printer that is different. Does anyone know of a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a program called DOSprn.